# Ordinary Least Squares to Fit a Cubic Spline

Tags: r, least-squares, splines

I want to use ordinary least squares to fit a cubic spline. I'm having a difficult time creating the design matrix for the ordinary least squares. Here is my problem:

```
x ~ Uniform(-pi, +pi)
y|x ~ (sin(x), (0.5|x| + 0.5)^2))
```

The code below is what I am currently using, but I do not want to use the function `ns`, I want to create the design matrix using the ordinary least squares.

```
library(splines)
fit.temp <- lm(y ~ ns(x, knots = c(1,2,3)))

fit.temp.values <- predict(fit.temp,interval="prediction", 
                           level = 1 - 0.05)
```

Comment: You wanted a natural cubic spline? Or did you want an ordinary cubic spline?

Comment: @Glen_b I want to fit a natural cubic regression to the data using ordinary least squares. I am trying to create a design matrix like this: b_1(x), b_2(x),..., b_{K-1}(x)

Comment: "I do not want to use the function 'ns,' I want to create the design matrix using the ordinary least squares." — But OLS isn't a method for creating design matrices. It takes a design matrix as one of its *inputs*, and what it does is estimate parameter values. The code you posted already uses OLS, via `lm`.

Comment: @Kodiologist Does my code estimate parameters values? I'm sorry, I'm really new to R.

Comment: @lovebug Yes, that's the primary thing that happens when you call the function `lm`.

Comment: @Kodiologist Is there a way to do what my code does without using the function "ns?"

Comment: @lovebug Sure, although I don't see the point. [Here's a description of the algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_cubic_spline#Algorithm_to_find_the_interpolating_cubic_spline)

Comment: @Kodiologist Thank you for the link, but is there a way to code it without using the function "ns"?

Comment: @lovebug Implement that algorithm. That's what I was suggesting.

Comment: What is the purpose of implementing it without using `ns`? Is this a class exercise, for example? (It seems an odd thing to require otherwise since both the R code of `ns` and the main function it calls - `splineDesign` - can be read simply by typing the function names)

Comment: @Kodiologis I am assigned to implement a natural spline with and without the "ns" function. I am supposed to create a design matrix using ordinary least squares. I am confused how I am supposed to implement this without the function "ns" and while still using R code.

Comment: @Glen_b I am assigned to implement a natural spline with and without the "ns" function. I am supposed to create a design matrix using ordinary least squares. I am confused how I am supposed to implement this without the function "ns" and while still using R code.

Comment: Assigned by whom? Again, is this a class exercise or something similar?

Comment: My understanding of splining is that u solves the matrix of polynomials. It is not a statistical operation but one for creating differentiable functions. I feel like the while question is wrong.